# CCAvenue SDK in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I m working on payment gateway in CCAvenue.I need to integrate CCAvenue in swift code but it is available only on objective-c.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to use Bridging header and then you can call objective c code  from swift and go with normal flow , i did with Paytm and HDFC Payment gateway for integrating it in swift and worked successfully.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..will work on it..

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)